# what class is returned after a delete action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs

I am using rails-ujs to delete an object,
my goal is to hide that div wit that obj after i delete it, i've done it before, but i cant get it this time, i think i need to know whats going on. 
on view:

```
<div class="employee_<%= employee.id %>" 
<%= link_to 'Destroy', employee, method: :delete, remote: true } %>
</div
```

on destroy.js.erb:

```
$('div.each-employee-data').find('div.employee_<%= @employee.id %>').hide(); # if i change the id to employee.id i get another error
```

controller:

```
format js
```

console error:

```
NoMethodError in Employees#destroy

Showing 
/Desktop/bad/current/app/views/employees/destroy.js.erb where line #1 
raised:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /Desktop/bad/current

Application Trace
app/views/employees/destroy.js.erb:1:in 
`_app_views_employees_destroy_js_erb__4462192751889852231_70177039108760'
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've destroyed a record - you should no longer use it, and it no longer have an `id`. For your case you can save the id prior to deleting in controller:

```rb
@deleted_employee_id = @employee.id
@employee.destroy
...
```

and in js view `...find('div.employee_<%= @deleted_employee_id %>').hide()...`

PS. Also it's common practice to use "soft deletes" - have a flag in model that indicates if the record was "deleted" and set it in `destroy` action, without actual delete, this is useful, if a user would want to "undo".

Comment: Thanks, i don spent 2hrs trying to figure that out.